# Tools for generating "dummy" data to DB for performance testing?

Tags: database, random, performance-testing

I am planning our performance testing in a large transactional web application. We do not have a production snapshot available that we could scramble, and I do not want to create manual SQL insert queries. Are there (preferably) free tools available that can generated randomized data to a database, preferably with some pre-defined rules for content?

Comment: did you perhaps look here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572537/create-dummy-data-with-while][1]


or here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570018/automatically-generate-sql-insert-statement-with-dummy-data][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572537/create-dummy-data-with-while
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570018/automatically-generate-sql-insert-statement-with-dummy-data

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.mockaroo.com.  It's a free tool that I maintain that my company uses to generate test datasets.  It will generate SQL DDL and insert statements for you and you can automate test data generation using curl if you sign in and save your schemas.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jFairy, this library helps generating random data (no sql). You need to create sql statements manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generatedata.com/ and http://www.databasetestdata.com/ for dummy data

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://genfu.io/ (You can generate sample data on the site itself)
or
https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu

It can generate realistic data even contact numbers and almost real names.